# if else in if else error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do a if else in another if else. But it has been giving me the error of Else without If. I have an if there but how come VBA does not see it?

```
a = Sheet1.ComboBox1.value
If unit <> a Then
  If a = "mils" Then
    Set cx = Sheet9.range("E2", Sheet9.range("E2").End(xlDown))
    For Each rng In cx
    rng.value = rng.value * y
  Else
    Set cx = Sheet9.range("E2", Sheet9.range("E2").End(xlDown))
    For Each rng In cx
    rng.value = rng.value / y
  End If
End If
```

Comment: Where are the `Next` for each `For Each`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `Next` for the `For`, which makes the `IF` and the `For` blocks interleaved.

```
a = Sheet1.ComboBox1.value
If unit <> a Then
  If a = "mils" Then
    Set cx = Sheet9.range("E2", Sheet9.range("E2").End(xlDown))
    For Each rng In cx
      rng.value = rng.value * y
    Next ' <------------------------------ Missing
  Else
    Set cx = Sheet9.range("E2", Sheet9.range("E2").End(xlDown))
    For Each rng In cx
      rng.value = rng.value / y
    Next ' <------------------------------- Missing
  End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax error for your `for each` statements

Here is the syntax for `For Each` loop in VBA:

```
For Each element In Group
   [statement 1]
   [statement 2]
   ....
   [statement n]
   [Exit For]
   [statement 11]
   [statement 22]
Next    //you are missing this line in your coding
```